# Wowza Token Validation

Tags: wowza

I'm trying to use Wowza as a Live Video server for a new feature in an existing app, and I need it to serve feeds only to authenticated users.

My idea is to send the client token to the Wowza server, and make Wowza request to the validation server if that token is valid.

- Is there any existing module to do this?
- If not, is it posible to do it creating a new module? 
  (that is, is it possible for the Wowza ModuleBase.onConnect() to "wait" for another http connection to check if the token is valid)

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own module based on the Wowza Server Side API, the thing that Wrench does is exactly what you mentioned: doing external calls and checks in the `onConnect`. However be careful, as `onConnect` (despite its name) is only triggered for RTMP clients, there are some other methods, like `onHttpSessionCreate`, which you also need to hook to if you want to authenticate non-flash clients, like Android / iPhone guys coming on HTTP based streaming technologies. I can answer further questions regarding these technical details.

Comment: This draft module can be useful to look at: http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?131 However it only works for Flash clients, as I mentioned above.

Comment: is it possible from the onConnect() (in my tests it is called every time i connect, regardless of rtsp/rtmp) to get a url param? something like "some_token" from rtmp://localhost:1935/LiveTest/SomeFile.stream?token=some_token ?

Comment: Yes it is. There is a method called getQueryStr() and you need to parse that on your own. Wrench does this too.

Comment: onConnect() wont't be called if you connect from say an iPhone to a Cupertino streamer. Try it!

Comment: so, which method should I use to validate a RTSP connection? onRTPSessionCreate?

Comment: If you only need to support Flash clients, then `onConnect` is fine. If you want to support other platform, not only the declining Flash, then you need to add all the 3 and refactor the code smartly to eliminate code triplication.

Comment: Note that the link given by @jabal in a previous comment has been moved to https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-do-user-authentication-for-flash-rtmp-client-using-jdbc-connection-to-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

There is a secure token v2 to protect your stream. You can also use RTMP Encryption ( or RTMP Secure ) for flash based player. On the otherhand refererValidate quarantee the client request from allowed domains. Also you can write your custom module with cupertino, mpegdash, rtsp, rtmp session create method like jabal said.